# Assigning model field value with dynamic field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a variable *param* that represents a field name in an ActiveRecord model.

I want to set the field to a specific value.

I know there are 2 ways of doing it (might be more), but my question is what's the difference between these 2 if any?

Are there any gotchas I should keep in mind or can I use both ways interchangeably?

1) Method 1

```
a = Article.find(3)
a[param] = "value"
a.save
```

2) Method 2

```
a = Article.find(3)
a.send("#{param}=", "value")
a.save
```

Comment: "#send" is the ruby method to pass dynamically a method.
There is one more common way to do it :
a.update_attribute(param, 'value') or a.update_attributes(param => 'value').

Comment: I would avoid using `send("#{param}=", "value")` as this can call to `private` methods instead for security reasons use `public_send` or since this is rails I would use `update_attribute` or `update_attributes`. Please note `update_attributes` will fire validation callbacks where as `update_attribute` will not. However both will fire save and it's callbacks. `public_send` and `send` will not fire call backs and will require a subsequent call to `save` for the results to be persisted.

Comment: @RaphaelPr I know this is an old question, but your comment should be an answer so we visitors from the future can provide feedback (like upvotes).

Comment: Done. Old indeed. I have try to updated it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `send("#{param}=", "value")` as this can call to private methods instead for security reasons use public_send.

Since this is rails I would use `update_attribute` or `update_attributes`. Please note `update_attributes` will fire validation callbacks while `update_attribute` will not.

In your example:

```rb
a = Article.find(3)
a.update_attribute(param, "value")

# or equivalent
a.assign_attribute(param, "value")
a.save
```

Regarding `[]=`, it is alias for `#write_attribute` (see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). More details/difference on attribute assignation, could be found at https://davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/